# Why PUSH CX is executed before PUSH BX is executed in PUSHA instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu, cpu-registers, cpu-architecture

I have been studying x86 assembler language and a question arises from PUSHA instruction.

As I know, Pusha is the same as PUSH AX, CX, DX, BX, original SP, BP, SI, and DI.
What I wondering is Why PUSH CX is executed before PUSH BX is executed in PUSHA instruction.

Is there any reason in hardware architecture?

Answer (score 8):

The general purpose registers are not alphabetically ordered, the letters are short cut for a word:

```
AX => Accumulator register
BX => Base register
CX => Counter register
DX => Data register
```

most people use `AX`, `BX`, `CX`, `DX` because it's easier to remember, but for the architecture, the order actually is `AX`, `CX`, `DX`, `BX` and this can be noties in the opcodes of the instructions:

```
 opcode | instruction
--------+------------------
B80000  | MOV     AX,0000
B90000  | MOV     CX,0000
BA0000  | MOV     DX,0000
BB0000  | MOV     BX,0000
50      | PUSH    AX
51      | PUSH    CX
52      | PUSH    DX
53      | PUSH    BX
```

Comment: Thank you for kind reply and sorry for late response. But after reading your reply, One more question was rise up. Why order of opcode  is not alphabetically ordered? Is any historical reason?

Comment: @joejo it is ordered by op code instead so you see the architecture use this order anywhere it can... it would make no sense adding remapping table to the CPU control unit or microcode just to reorder the operands not to match register file addresses (that would waste time, transistors and chip space and lower power dissipation).

Comment: I think the question remains why were the opcodes designed this way, instead of opting for a way coinciding with the alphabetic order.